# Get photos posted on instagram in my app

Tags: ios

How do I list photos that are posted on instagram by the current user logged in to my app. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: You may wish to add more specifics to have a more complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

You'll find there is an exhaustive set of information at http://instagram.com/developer/ .  Given you haven't stated whether you have registered for the API yet (I'm suspecting not), then you would follow the "3 Step Plan" detailed by Instagram:

> **1) Register**
>
> We'll assign an OAuth client_id and client_secret for each of your
>   applications.
>
> **2) Authenticate**
>
> Have our user authenticate and authorize your application with
>   Instagram.
>
> **3)  Start making requests!**
>
> Make requests to our API Endpoints with your authenticated OAuth
>   credentials.

A basic API request like that suggested by your question, to list the recent media for a particular user would be given by:

`https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/3/media/recent/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN`

As another example, the request for 'the most popular photos at the moment' would be given by:

`https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/popular?client_id=CLIENT-ID` where `CLIENT-ID` is your ID provided by API registration.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I went through the link http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/ and nowhere I found API to list photos shared by the particular user. All I want to do is log into instagram through my app and my app has to show the photos shared by logged in user.

Comment: `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/3/media/recent/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN` .  Find more info on accessing the media for a particular user [here](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/) and I updated the above answer with some more information pertaining to your question.

Comment: Is there a way to show all the pictures of particular #hagtag? Lets say I want to pull all photos from hashtag #stanford like following link.

http://statigr.am/viewer.php#/tag/stanford/

Is it possible?

Comment: @mysticboy59 - absolutely.  Use the above info I gave for starting out and then check out http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/ .  Statigr.am likely uses the same methods :)

Comment: @TomJowett Thanks tom, i did it. Your information helped me a lot ;)